# Извлечь данные из столбца DataFrame формата словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas, dict

В столбце 'production countries' (pandas.DataFrame) датасета 'data' все данные выглядят подобным образом:  `[{"iso_3166_1": "IN", "name": "India"}]` и имеют тип `object`. Необходимо переделать подобные строки в `'India'` (для этого примера). В общем случае шаблон выглядит так:  [{"iso_3166_1": "XX", "name": "COUNTRY"}] надо переделать в "COUNTRY" для всего столбца в датасете. К тому же в столбце есть такие значения `[]`, их надо игнорировать. Пробовала создать функцию по типу такого:

```py
def extract_country(row):
    if row==[]:
      return row
    else:
      import json
      return lambda row: json.loads(row)['name']
data['production countries'] = data['production countries'].apply(extract_country)
```

но в таком случае в столбец добавляются значения `<function extract_country.<locals>.<lambda> at...`

Ещё была попытка воспользоваться помощью gpt:

```py
def extract_country_name(country):
    country_dict = eval(country)  # преобразуем строку в словарь
    if isinstance(country_dict, list) and len(country_dict) > 0:  # проверяем, что это список и он не пустой
        country_name = country_dict[0].get('name')  # извлекаем название страны из словаря
        if country_name:  # проверяем, что название страны не пустое
            return country_name
    return country  # если что-то пошло не так, возвращаем исходное значение

data['countries'] = data['countries'].apply(extract_country_name)
```

Но в этом случае возникает ошибка при выводе

Comment: Уберите `lambda row: ` зачем оно там нужно? И нужно заменить `json.loads(row)['name']` на `json.loads(row)[0]['name']`.

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно писать такую большую функцию, вот вариант с помощью лямбда функции:

```
df['production countries'] = df['production countries'].apply(lambda x: x if x == [] else x[0]['name'])
```

Если я правильно понял, когда строка-пустой список-ее не меняем, когда строка-список с одним элементом в виде словаря, то берем значение ключа name в этом словаре.

Comment: да, так тоже можно, спасибо.  Однако потом мне понадобилось заполнять ячейки значениями 'name' из всех элементов списка, и таких столбцов оказалось несколько. Поэтому всё же написала функцию

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось:

```py
def extract_country(json_string):
    # Преобразование строки JSON в список Python
    country_list = json.loads(json_string)
    # Проверка на []
    if len(country_list) > 0:
        # Извлечение названия страны из первого элемента списка
        country_dict = country_list[0]
        country_name = country_dict['name']
        return country_name
    else:
        return []

# Применение функции extract_country к столбцу 'production countries'
data['production countries'] = data['production countries'].apply(extract_country)
```

Теперь всё работает как нужно: столбец заполняется извлечёнными названиями стран

Для случая, когда в ячейках содержится не просто словарь, а список словарей с одинаковыми ключами и нужно выбрать оттуда все значения с ключом 'name':

```py
def extract_names(json_string):
    new_list = json.loads(json_string)  # преобразование строки JSON в список Python
    # проверка наличия элементов в списке
    if len(new_list) > 0:
        list_of_dicts=[]
        # извлечение необходимых названий из всех словарей списка
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
          list_of_dicts.append(new_list[i])
          list_of_names = [country_dict['name'] for country_dict in list_of_dicts]
        return list_of_names
    else:
        return []
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью [pandas.Series.str.get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), в короткой записи `.str[]`:

```
data = pd.Series([[{"iso_3166_1": "IN", "name": "India"}], [], [{"iso_3166_1": "CN", "name": "China"}]]).to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'production countries'})
print('\nИсходный фрейм\n', data)
mask = ~data['production countries'].str[0].isna() # создаем булев массив для обработки только тех строк, где непустой список
data.loc[mask,'production countries'] = data.loc[mask,'production countries'].str[0].str['name']  # выделяем сначала нулевой элемент списка (словарь), потом из словаря - значение по ключу
print('\nРезультат\n', data)
```

```
Исходный фрейм
                       production countries
0  [{'iso_3166_1': 'IN', 'name': 'India'}]
1                                       []
2  [{'iso_3166_1': 'CN', 'name': 'China'}]

Результат
   production countries
0                India
1                   []
2                China
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно все векторизовать в довольно компактный код:

дано:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"country":[[{"iso_3166_1": "IN", "name": "India"}],
                              [{"iso_3166_2": "RU", "name": "Russia"}],
                              [],
                              [{"iso_3166_2": "EC", "name": "Ecuador"}]]})
```

```
                                     country
0    [{'iso_3166_1': 'IN', 'name': 'India'}]
1   [{'iso_3166_2': 'RU', 'name': 'Russia'}]
2                                         []
3  [{'iso_3166_2': 'EC', 'name': 'Ecuador'}]
```

решение:

```
df["country"] = df["country"].str[0].fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.get("name") if x else [])
```

получаем df:

```
   country
0    India
1   Russia
2       []
3  Ecuador
```

Answer (score 0):

Делаем из столбца своего рода датафрейм, прибавляем его в обозначенные до "равно" столбцы

```
data[['iso', 'Country']] = data['production countries'].apply(pd.Series)
```